# Remove all control characters from a Java string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string coming from a UI that contains control characters such as line feeds and carrage returns.

I would like to do something like this:

```
String input = uiString.replaceAll(<regex for all control characters> , "")
```

Surely this has been done before!?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", "");
```

Comment: -1; this doesn't even cover all *ASCII* control characters; the DEL character (`\u007F`) is not in the range you've specified.

Answer (score 27):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), probably more efficient than using the full regex engine, and certainly more readable...

```
return CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL.removeFrom(string);
```

Alternately, just using regexes, albeit not quite as readably or efficiently...

```
return string.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

Comment: How to remove all control characters except **carriage returns**, **line feeds**, and **tabs**.

Comment: I might've answered that if that had been specified in the questions, but I'd do that with `CharMatcher.anyOf("\r\n\t").removeFrom(string)`.

Comment: The `replaceAll` incantation shown here only gets ASCII control characters; if you need to kill Unicode ones too, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458616/1709587).

Answer (score 8):

To remove just ASCII control characters, use the [`Cntrl` character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix)

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

To remove all 65 of the characters that Unicode refers to as "control characters", use the `Cntrl` character class in [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) mode, with the `(?U)` flag:

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("(?U)\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

To additionally remove unicode "format" characters - things like the control characters for making text go right-to-left, or the [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) - also nuke the `Cf` character class:

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("(?U)\\p{Cntrl}|\\p{Gc=Cf}", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Guava** CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL is deprecated, use **javaIsoControl()** instead:

```
CharMatcher.javaIsoControl().removeFrom(string);
```