# Ignoring blank lines in CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv, io, iteration, bufferedreader

I am trying to iterate through a CSV file in Java. It iterates through the entire file, but will get to the end of the file and try to read the next blank line and throw an error. My code is below.

```
public class Loop() {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";

    try {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> changeData = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\the_file.csv"));
        String headerLine = br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(",");

            /*Below is my latest attempt at fixing this,*/ 
            /*but I've tried other things too.*/
            if (data[0].equals("")) { break; }

            System.out.println(data[0] + " - " + data[6]);
            int changeId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            int changeCv = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);

            changeData.put(changeId, changeCv);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}
}
```

Like I typed, this works fine until it gets to the end of the file. When it gets to the end of the file, I get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at com.ucg.layout.ShelfTableUpdates.main(ShelfTableUpdates.java:23)`. I've stepped through the code by debugging it in Spring Tool Suite. The error comes up whenever I try to reference data[0] or data[6]; likely because there is nothing in that line. Which leads me back to my original question of why it is even trying to read the line in the first place.

It was my understanding that `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` would detect the end of the file, but it doesn't seem to be. I've tried re-opening the file and deleting all of the blank rows, but that did not work.

Any idea how I can detect the end of the file so I don't get an error in this code?

**ANSWER:**
Credit goes to user @quemeraisc. I also was able to replace the commas with blanks, and if the line then equals null or "", then you know that it is the end of the file; in my case, there are no blank rows before the end of the file. This still does not solve the problem of detecting the end of the file in that if I did have blank rows in between my data that were not the EOF then this would detect those.

**Solution 1:**

```
if (data.length < 7) {
    System.out.println(data.length);
    break;
}
```

**Solution 1:**

```
if (line.replace(",", "").equals(null) || line.replace(",", "").equals("")) {
    System.out.println(line.replace(",", ""));
    break;
}
```

Comment: I ran your program as it was posted and did not get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public String readLine()` will read a line from your file, even empty lines. Thus, when you split your line, as in `String[] data = line.split(",");` you get an array of size 1.
Why not try :

```
if (data.length >= 7)
{
    System.out.println(data[0] + " - " + data[6]);
    int changeId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    int changeCv = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);
    changeData.put(changeId, changeCv);
}
```

which will make sure there are at least 7 elements in your array before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip all blank lines:

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if( line.trim().isEmpty() ) {
          continue;
     }
     ....
     ....
```

The last line may contain some control characters (like new line, carriage return, EOF and others unvisible chars), in this case a simple String#trim() doesn't remove them, see this answer to know how to remove them: [How can i remove all control characters from a java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057083/how-can-i-remove-all-control-characters-from-a-java-string)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried this, and it doesn't work. It is still recognizing the blank lines as not empty.

Comment: Hart to say without seeing the content of the file - You need to debug the code and check what does this line contain. Make copy of the file, remove all lines except the ones that cause a problem, then set a breakpoin just after `while`, run a program in the debugger, and examine what is in this line.

Answer (score 0):

To skip blank lines you could try:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if(line.length() > 0) {
      String[] data = line.split(",");

        /*Below is my latest attempt at fixing this,*/ 
        /*but I've tried other things too.*/
        if (data[0] == null || data[0].equals("")) { break; }

        System.out.println(data[0] + " - " + data[6]);
        int changeId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        int changeCv = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);

        changeData.put(changeId, changeCv);
   }           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. It is still returning the length of the blank line as 17, even though the blank line is reading in my console as `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace method use replaceAll method. Then it will work.